# Material 2 for Angular 2 throwing errors

Tags: angular, angular-material

How to deal with this errors of Material 2 for Angular 2:

[image]

```
 client:75 [default] /Users/mateo/Desktop/app/client/node_modules/@angular/material/core/gestures/MdGestureConfig.d.ts:4:39 
Cannot find name 'HammerManager'.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the following:

1 Install `types` for hammerjs:

```
npm install @types/hammerjs --save-dev
```

2 Open `\node_modules\@angular\material\tsconfig.json` and add installed `hammerjs` types to `types` array this config:

```
"types": [
  "hammerjs"
]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you need to install `HammerJS` because you're using `Material` component that requires it:

`npm install hammerjs --save`

**systemjs.config.js**

```
System.config({
    path: {'npm:' : 'node_modules/'},
    map:  {'hammerjs': 'npm:hammerjs'},
    packages: {
        'hammerjs':  { main: './hammer.js', defaultExtension: 'js'}
    }
})
```

A few Material components (eg: `md-slider`) import `hammerjs`, so unless it's installed or linked via an external script (as in @Gunter's answer), you will run into problems.